# textbox is not getting focus using jquery focus

Tags: asp.net, jquery

I am working on as asp.net application. I have following jquery code to focus on textbox if  checkbox is checked in document.ready. checkbox is checked but textbox is not getting focus

```
 $('#isUniquePassword').is(':checked') ? $("#UniquePassword").show() : $("#UniquePassword").hide();
            if ($('#isUniquePassword').is(':checked')) {
                alert($('#isUniquePassword').is(':checked'));
                $("#UniquePassword").focus();
            }
```

Comment: @scott: I am using asp.net mvc

Comment: How to you trigger it to run ?

Comment: are these  checkboxes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Suggestion:** you can try this :

```
$('#isUniquePassword').attr('checked') ? $("#UniquePassword").show() : $("#UniquePassword").hide();
            if ($('#isUniquePassword').is(':checked')) {
                alert($('#isUniquePassword').is(':checked'));
                $("#UniquePassword").focus();
            }
```

---

or

```
  $('#isUniquePassword').prop("checked")
```